# Facebook custom CSS for fanbox not working

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-likebox

So I'm using this code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.connect.facebook.com/widgets/fan.php?href=http://www.facebook.com/pages/TopDesenecom/148037301911330&width=205&height=256&show_faces=true&stream=false&header=false&css=http://topdesene.com/template/fb.css"></iframe>
```

and facebook shows this code:

```
<link href="http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/fbml_static_get.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Ftopdesene.com%2Ftemplate%2Ffb.css&appid=148037301911330&pv=1&sig=59bf9a037df3a88cb6ff142f25227177&filetype=css&cb=2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

but that url doesn't return my css, it shows nothing...

anyone willing to help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. Apparently I need to add a ?XXXX where XXX is a number of the current version... and the link seems to add the class automatically

Comment: http://miklasnjor.com/en/2011/css-style-facebook-fanbox-fanpage-facepile-pagestream/#css-style-fanbox-tips Has it explained with highlighted images marking every part. But FB's markup has changed and probably dont support external CSS anymore.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-simple-facebook-connect-fanbox-custom-css-isnt-working Has the answer at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use custom CSS in the Facebook like box.

The `css` parameter is presumably for Facebook-only use and will only accept their own domains.

Comment: there are many tutorials on the internet that got it working so it has to work

Comment: There are plenty of non-functional tutorials. Clearly, you're not managing to get it to work. They probably just patched whatever security holes your tutorial was using.

Comment: WRONG! This guy got it working: http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-your-facebook-fan-box/ . check his page box

Comment: Then do whatever he did. And don't plan on it working for long. Facebook tends to disable exploits so people can't customize the Like boxes, as it's often abused.

Comment: lol since they added that option it's clearly they added it for a reason. And I didn't post here to get such rude answers "do whatever he did". If you don't know, don't answer.

Comment: "For a reason" doesn't mean "for the reason I want". Don't depend on this continuing to work forever. Hell, their **intentional, documented** APIs often break.